# Is there simple straight forward in Powershell on how to run code in parallelism?

Tags: powershell

I have arrays each storing 6553 elements I want to run these arrays in parallel to make the processing faster however I am struggling to achieve that what am I missing please help for example is there a one to do this so I can implement it any time. Here is what I have I tried so far.

```
class CommonServicePorts {
    [int]$numberOfPorts = 65535;
    [int]$divisor = 10;
    [int]$roundedDown;
    [int[]] $last = @();
    [void] GetAllPorts() {
        $this.roundedDown = [Math]::Floor($this.numberOfPorts / $this.divisor);
        $fromStartToNPort = $this.roundedDown;
        for ($i = 1; $i -le $this.divisor; $i++) {
            $ports = @($i..($fromStartToNPort * $i - 1));
            $jobs = @(
                $ports | ForEach-Object -Parallel {
                    $_
                } -AsJob
            )

            $results = $jobs | Receive-Job -Wait -AutoRemoveJob
            Write-Output $results;
    
        }
    }
    [void]lastSection() {
         write-host $this.last;
    }
} 

$ports = [CommonServicePorts]::new();
$ports.GetAllPorts();
```

Comment: Add `-Wait -AutoRemoveJob` to `Receive-Job` then its fine ;)

Comment: Now, after this new edit, the issue is `Write-Output $results` from a `void` method. Change the return type of `GetAllPorts` to `int[]` and it would work. But also you're using `Receive-Job` from within the `for` loop, that doesnt look right

Comment: I am using it within the for loop because I have 10 arrays each storing 6553 I wan them to run in parallel without for loop I can't do that

Comment: @ayyub41 The loop is fine, it's the method signature you need to change. `[void] GetAllPorts()` should be `[int[]] GetAllPorts()`

Comment: `$results = $jobs | Receive-Job -Wait -AutoRemoveJob` inside the `for` loop is blocking the iteration.

Comment: Or take out the -asjob and receive-job.